# POST 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm working on a Python app that uses jQuery to smart-select districts when the correct city is selected and cities when the correct country is selected, so visitors need not refresh their browser.

I get this error on Chrome console:

> POST [Localhost url] 500 (Internal Server Error)

Here is my testing code:

```
   <header>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" /> 
      <script>
         function selectCountry(){
            $.ajax({
               type: 'POST',
               url: '/',
               data: 'countrySelect=1',

            });
            console.log(events);
         }

      </script>
   </header>

   <body>
      <script>
         var var1 = $_POST('countrySelect');
         document.write(var1);
      </script>

      <select onchange="javascript:selectCountry()">
         <option name="" value="">country a</option>
         <option name="" value="">country b</option>
      </select>
  </body>
```

Changing to `GET` works fine but doesn't show the variables on the navigation bar.

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 500 means "Look in your server logs for your error". You need to share that with us.

Comment: Seems like the Server doesnt like POST requests

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error means the error is on your server, not the client.

Comment: What is `$_POST` doing in your JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Changing to GET would not show the variable on the nav bar because its an ajax request.
To troubleshoot this use fiddler (or your browser's session inspector) to see the actual request.
I would also change the data to a json object such as { countrySelect:"1" }